# Understanding performed change of variabile in this integration

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm stuck on a passage I do not understand, which reads:

> $$\int_{r<|y|<1} \bigg| \frac{1}{(|y|^2 - r^2)^s |y|^n} - \frac{1}{|y|^{n+2s}}\bigg|\ \text{d}y$$
> $$\int_1^r \bigg| \frac{1}{(t^2 - r^2)^s} - \frac{1}{t^{2s}}\bigg|\ \frac{\text{d}t}{t}$$
> $$r^{s}\int_1^{1/r} \bigg| \frac{1}{(\tau^2 - 1)^s} - \frac{1}{\tau^{2s}}\bigg|\ \frac{\text{d}\tau}{\tau}$$

I understood there is a sort of rescaling between the second and the third line, but I cannot find a way to get the passage between the first and the second line.
I thought about a change of variable like $|y|^n = t$ but there is something that I miss, and it doesn't work.

This is an integral in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $0<s<1$.

Comment: Have you considered polar coordinates?

Comment: Only the first integral is in $\Bbb R^n$. The latter two integrals are one-dimensional. It is in integrating out the other $n - 1$ dimensions that a fractor of $\frac 1{|y|^n}$ gets converted to a factor of $\frac 1{|y|}$ (and some constant that they hid by "rescaling") for the substitution $t = |y|$ in the final 1D integral.